# iOS 7 Apply filters on UIImagePickerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-camera

Hi i try to build simple camera app with filters. I apply CIFilters on UIImage that works fine but now i want apply filters before take photo(live filter on camera) like iOS7 camera below.

[image]

Thank in advance.

Comment: Use GPUImage library, iOS default filters are not available for use in apps or you can go with CoreImage framework

Comment: I don't want iOS7 filters, i want to apply the filters on camera while take photo (before takePicture). Camera stream

Comment: Go for GPU Image yes you have to do the work around

Answer (score 0):

CoreImage filters available for developers is too slow for real-time processing.

As suggested above, use a GPU-accelerated library, such as [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for api of UIImagePickerController to make a real-time camera filtering, it won't happened. 
You must build your own.

Check out AVCaptureSession, and maybe [this sample code](https://github.com/xissburg/XBImageFilters)(see `XBFilteredCameraView.m`) to help you understand how to capture camera output image in real-time.

And you also need a real-time image processing library, such as [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage).

Hope this can help you.